# Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

I can't seem to figure out why the left side equals the right side

[image]

Comment: what exactly is the problem? what have you tried? btw your title is not very concise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\left| \frac{1}{z^2+1}\right| &=\frac{1}{|z^2+1|}\\
&= \frac{1}{|(Re^{i\theta})^2+1|}\\
&=\frac{1}{|R^2e^{i2\theta}+1|}\\
&=\frac{1}{|R^2\cos(2\theta)+iR^2\sin(2\theta)+1|}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(R^2\cos(2\theta)+1)^2+(R^2\sin(2\theta))^2}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{R^4\cos^2(2\theta)+2R^2\cos(2\theta)+1+R^4\sin^2(2\theta)}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{R^4+2R^2\cos(2\theta)+1}}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Note that 
$$z^2+1 = R^2 \text{e}^{i 2\theta}+1 =  R^2(\cos(2\theta)+i\sin(2\theta))+1$$
is a complex number of the form $z^2+1=x+iy$, where
$$
x = R^2 \cos(2\theta)+1 \qquad \text{ and } \qquad y = R^2 \sin(2\theta).
$$
Hence we have 
\begin{align*}
|z^2+1|^2 &= x^2+y^2= R^4 \cos^2(2\theta)+2R^2\cos(2\theta)+1+R^4\sin^2(2\theta)\\
&=R^4 \underbrace{\big(\cos^2(2\theta)+\sin^2(2\theta)\big)}_{=1}  +2R^2\cos(2\theta)+1\\
&=R^4+2R^2\cos(2\theta)+1.
\end{align*}
Taking the square root we get
$$
|z^2+1| = \sqrt{R^4+2R^2\cos(2\theta)+1},
$$
which is your result.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: note that $|z|^2=z \overline{z}$, then some algebra. Keep also in mind that $\frac{e^{i \theta}+e^{-i \theta}}{2}=\cos(\theta)$.